# Timestamp on edit from a specific column

Tags: javascript

I am trying to have a timestamp using google sheets. I already have a script that does this every time the sheet is being edited. However, what I want is for the timestamp to be applied when a specific column header is being updated.

I have a column named "STATUS" which is in column G. I just want that only when this column is being edited will it trigger the script to record a timestamp in column L, named "LAST UPDATED".

Current Script I am using is:

```
function onEdit(event)
{ 
  var timezone = "PST";
  var timestamp_format = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a zzz";
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();

  // note: actRng = the cell being updated
  var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var index = actRng.getRowIndex();

  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf('LAST UPDATED');

  if (dateCol > -1 && index > 1) { // only timestamp if 'Last Updated' header exists, but not in the header row itself!
    var cell = sheet.getRange(index, dateCol + 1);
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timestamp_format);
    cell.setValue(date);
  }
}
```

I also found the script in this forum but was not able to find anything about my question above.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Below is a script I am currently using.  My knowledge of JavaScript is very limited but it should do what you're asking for.  However, I'm still having difficulty getting the IF RETURN null value to work. So feel free to provide feedback there.

I then format the column to include date/time, but you can easily format the script appropriately.

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "Sheet1" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 2 ) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, -1);
      if(s.getActiveCell() == null) { //is empty?
        return nextCell.setValue(null) ;
      } 
      else {
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
      }
    }
  }
```